# Is it possible to turn a pandas df that has duplicate named columns into json/dictionary?

Tags: python, pandas

[image]

I attempted to call .to_dict() but it only returns the last column

Comment: Please post data as text rather than image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to export multiple columns with identical names using `to_dict`. The only possible way is using [`to_json`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_json) with `'split'` orientation:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1,10],[2,20],[3,30]], columns = ['col1','col1'])
print(df)
#   col1  col1
#0     1    10
#1     2    20
#2     3    30

json = df.to_json(orient='split')
print(json)
#{"columns":["col1","col1"],"index":[0,1,2],"data":[[1,10],[2,20],[3,30]]}

print(pd.read_json(json,'split'))
#   col1  col1
#0     1    10
#1     2    20
#2     3    30
```